# Update style on newly rendered li element

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I want to render a list, and then select one of the list elements and apply style changes to it based on an index.

At the moment it seems like the style change is being applied before the list is rendered, so the style changes are overwritten.

What is the best way to update the list and then apply style changes to one of the elements?

component -

```
<aura:attribute name="testList" type="List" default="['example1', 'example2', 'example3']"/>

 <div>
     <ul>
        <aura:iteration items="{! v.testList }" var="li" indexVar="index">
            <li class="row-element" onclick="{!c.displayCurrentRecord }" id="{! 'test-row-' + index }" data-index="{! index }" >
                <span class="slds-truncate slds-text-body_regular slds-text-color_default" title="">{! li }</span>
            </li> 
        </aura:iteration>
    </ul>
     <button onclick="{! c.changeList }">Next Item</button>
 </div>
```

controller -

```
changeList: function(component, event, helper){
        let newList = ["example4", "example5", "example6"];
        component.set("v.testList", newList);
        let currentElement = document.getElementById('test-row-0');
        $A.util.addClass(currentElement, 'selected-element');
    }
```

style -

```
.THIS .selected-element {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this one to another javascript method, inside helper i guess. `$A.util.addClass(currentElement, 'selected-element');`

**CONTROLLER:**

```
changeList: function(component, event, helper){
        let newList = ["example4", "example5", "example6"];
        component.set("v.testList", newList);
        helper.applyStyle(component, event);
    }
```

**HELPER:**

```
applyStyle : function(cmp, evt){
            let currentElement = document.getElementById('test-row-0');
            $A.util.addClass(currentElement, 'selected-element');
}
```

Comment: Hiya - doesn't seem to work!

Comment: Try adding a setTimeout function to the addClass if you believe that the styling really comes first before the data refresh.